# How to make simple error handling in Python?

Tags: python

When my script doesn't find an specific cell in excel file it throws an error and stops entire scripts. I don't want this to happen!

```
'Total Employees':  '{}'.format(df.iloc[1]['5A'])
```

And error massage from console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\szyma\Desktop\python_shit\index.py", line 25, in <module>
    'Total Employees':  '{}'.format(df.iloc[row_iterator]['5A']),
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 824, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 932, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: '5A'
```

Instead, I want to paste in curly braces for example ***'empty'***. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use `dict.get(key, DEFAULT_VALUE)` or use a `try ... except KeyError`

Answer (score 1):

`'Total Employees':  '{}'.format(df.iloc[1].get('5A', 'empty'))`

Answer (score 1):

```py
try:
    print('Total Employees :  {}'.format(df.iloc[1]['5A']))
except KeyError:
    print("Total Employees : empty")
```